# Not able to check whether file exists

Tags: android, file, kotlin, exists

I'm trying to download a file and if it exists to delete it and download again. 
The download works. But the function `checkFile` never finds the file and I don't know why.

```
private fun startDownloading() {

        checkFile()

        val url = etUrl.text.toString()
        val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
        //allow type of networks to download file(s) by default, by default both are allowed
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes((DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI))
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "$folderName/$fileName")

        //get download service, and enqueue file
        val manager = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
        manager.enqueue(request)
    }


    private fun checkFile(){
        val file = File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "$folderName/$fileName")
        if(file.exists()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "File exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            file.delete()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, file.toString() + " doesn't exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You create the file in the public external storage directory with:

```
     request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
        "$folderName/$fileName"
    )
```

but you try to read it, from a relative (from the application's current directory) path:

```
    val file = File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "$folderName/$fileName")
```

You need to use the downloads directory, relative to the public external storage directory:

```
    val file = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "$folderName/$fileName")
```

Comment: maybe the intent was to set the destination in the app path?